# How to draw parametric region with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For example: if I want to draw
x= cos(t), y=sin(t) t=0..2pi

```py
x=cos(linspace(0,2*pi,100))
y=sin(linspace(0,2*pi,100))
plot(x,y)
```

but if I want to plot

x= r*cos(t), y=r* sin(t) t=0..2pi , r=0..3

How to do it?

what I want is this:

[image]

Since there are two vars: t and r, so the graph is shadow instead of curve. Now I plot it like this:

```py
from pylab import *
t = linspace(0, 3, 100)

for r in linspace(0, 2*pi, 100):
    x = r*sin(t)
    y = r*cos(t)
    plot(x, y)
show()
```

I have to write a loop to plot each curve, which I feel not so elegant.

> Maybe it's the only way to plot it?

Comment: Why can't you do it the same way?

Comment: `t = linspace(0,2*pi,100)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `for` loop:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(9, 3))

axes1 = plt.subplot()

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

for r in range(1, 3):
    x = r * np.cos(t)
    y = r * np.sin(t)
    axes1.plot(x, y)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You can also define the step(default is 1) from start to stop in `range` function. -> [range(start, stop[, step])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

**Note:** `range(start, stop)` will generate numbers in [start, stop).